# Get error message from Python/clang.cindex C++ parser

Tags: python, compilation, clang, llvm-c++-api

The following Python code is supposed to parse C++ code:

```py
import clang.cindex

index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
translation_unit = index.parse(cpp_source_filename, args=['-std=c++20'])
```

Problems start if function `parse` raises a `TranslationUnitLoadError`. If I catch and print the `TranslationUnitLoadError` instance, I only get "Error parsing translation unit."

How to get a decent compiler error message, or at least the location of the error in the source file?

Web search yields the advise to look into `translation_unit.diagnostics` - but this is not pertinent here because the error is raised before `translation_unit` is set.